# How to set color of text to red for the highest value in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to set  the highest value for 'LeadTime' which is in the gridview to red.

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim LeadTime As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "LeadTime"))
            If LeadTime > 0 Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
       End If
End If
```

Comment: Use the DataGridView.CellFormatting event

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to iterate through all the rows of Grid View to find the highest value of Lead Time like:

```
int maxLeadTime=0;
int maxRowIndex=0;
for(int i=0;i<yourGv.Rows.Count;i++)
{
    int currentLeadTime =Convert.ToInt32(yourGv.Rows[i].FindControl("idOfControlStoresLeadTime").ToString());
    if(maxLeadTime<currentLeadTime)
    {
        maxLeadTime=currentLeadTime;
        maxRowIndex=i;
    }
}
```

now you can set the forcolor of that row using following:

```
yourGv.Rows[maxRowIndex].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Above solution will set the fore color of highest value of lead time to Red.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do so. The simplest one (I think) is to obtain the *index* of row of max(LeadTime).

```
gridView1.Rows(obtainedRowIndex).ForeColor=System.Drawing.Color.Blue
```

Comment: I want to change the color of the text in gridview for the highest value of leadtime, even if there are duplicates.